# standalone package -> Error Message: infeasable parameter

Tags: document-classes, standalone

I try to convert tex2png  with the following lines and use

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
```

The following lines are in the text.tex

```
\documentclass[
  preview,
  convert
 ]{standalone}
 \begin{document}
   Hello. This is a test.
 \end{document}
```

If I try to compile I get the message:

"Infeasable parameter 300"

I didn't find any hints about this problem and hope that any body met this  problem before.

**Update:**

My operating system is windows 7.

Comment: Do you have imagemagick installed? It is needed.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: No, I did not extra install imagemagick. I will try, thank you

Comment: I installed it, but the same error appears again.

Comment: `infeasible parameter` or `invalid parameter` (I could explain the latter)

Comment: the error message was written in german (unzulässiger Parameter) an I translated it directly. "invalid" would also be a possible translation

Comment: @DerJFK thought that might be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be thankful you got an error message rather than convert running..

the package is trying to run imagemagic `convert` to convert image formats. On windows you need to make sure that imagemagic is ahead of the standard windows utilities as they include a convert command that ypu really don't want to run.

```
C:\Users\davidc>convert /?
Converts a FAT volume to NTFS.

CONVERT volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:filename] [/NoSecurity] [/X]


  volume      Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
              mount point, or volume name.
  /FS:NTFS    Specifies that the volume will be converted to NTFS.
  /V          Specifies that Convert will be run in verbose mode.
  /CvtArea:filename
              Specifies a contiguous file in the root directory
              that will be the place holder for NTFS system files.
  /NoSecurity Specifies that the security settings on the converted
              files and directories allow access by all users.
  /X          Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
              All open handles to the volume will not be valid.
```

That is, it wants to reformat your disk;-)

If you give it some image filenames you get (in English) an error such as

```
C:\Users\davidc>convert a.ps a.pdf
Invalid Parameter - a.pdf
```

So you need to make sure that imagemagic is installed and that `convert` finds that not the standard windows convert utility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it is true :). I already installed imagemagick, but how can I change, that convert leads to imagemagick and not to reformat my disk?

Comment: I installed imagemagick again and now the convert command is right.

Comment: @DerJFK No need to panic! By default standalone uses `imgconvert` as executable if MS Windows is detected. So go to the installation folder of imagemagick and make a copy of `convert.exe` and rename it `imgconvert.exe`.

Comment: @HarishKumar yes although changing the path is just as easy isn't it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not always and not for beginners for they will mess up the variables.